# Execute some codes when the user closes the current webpage

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net-2010

I want to execute some `vb.net` codes when the user leaves the current webpage. I know how to show an alert by using a `javascript` code but as I said I want(for example) to show a message on a `Label` or save some information in a `database` just before showing the `javascript alert`. Here is the alert message:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim message As String = "Good Bye"
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append("window.onbeforeunload=function(){")
        sb.Append("alert('")
        sb.Append(message)
        sb.Append("')};")
        sb.Append("</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())
   End Sub
```

Comment: you don't alert in onbeforeunload(), all you really can/should do is return a string. you can use `onunload()` to do more, as well as beacons, where supported.

Comment: VB.NET runs on the server side. You'd have to make an AJAX call to the server when they close the page.

Comment: So what should I do if I wanted to execute some codes just before client close the webpage?

Comment: @user1605859 I think this link will helps you... http://forums.asp.net/t/1305363.aspx